# what events are triggered in Excel Object Model

Tags: c#, excel, events, add-in, excel-dna

VS2008, .NET35, Excel AddIn, Excel-DNA, NetOffice 
In order to disable/enable ribbon buttons, I capture 3 events 
(e.g if users select a cell, the formula of the cell is MyUDF1, then buttons/menu items not-related to MyUDF1 will be grayed out.)

```
            XLApp.SheetSelectionChangeEvent += ApplicationSheetSelectionChange;
            XLApp.SheetDeactivateEvent += SheetDeactivatedEvent;
            XLApp.SheetCalculateEvent += ApplicationSheetCalculate;
```

However, this is a big performance hit
when users copy entire sheet and paste to another sheet 
or when users select columns and do autofit, Excel seems hang for 2-3 minutes
Anyone knows a solution?
thanks a lot!

Hello, 
If there is some tool I can use to run on client's PC to find out what's going on in Excel when copy/paste happens? I try process monitor but it seems not detail enough and I cant get any useful info from there.